# Rails : How to save the pdf file generated using wicked pdf

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, pdf-generation, wicked-pdf

I am using [WickedPdf](https://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf)

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html
  format.pdf do
    render :pdf => "file_name"
  end
end
```

This is  working fine . the user is able to download the generated pdf . but i need to store the generated pdf in server for other purposes like mailing etc etc 
How can i save this generated pdf ?

i tried the following but no idea how to pass the html to wickedpdf
[wicked_pdf doesn't work -- Ruby on Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4291411/wicked-pdf-doesnt-work-ruby-on-rails)

thanks in advance

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You probably figured this out already, but I'm learning WickedPdf right now and just learned how to save directly in your controller in the respond_to block. There is great documentation on the Git page for this https://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf. Here's what I have in my controller for the show action:

```
  def show
@user = User.find(params[:id])
respond_to do |format|
  format.html # show.html.erb
  format.pdf do
    render :pdf => "#{@user.name}",
    :save_to_file => Rails.root.join('pdfs', "#{@user.name}.pdf")
  end
end
end
```

This ends up saving it to a folder in my root called "pdfs" as the username.pdf. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I'm aware you cannot save files from the respond_to block directly, you'll need some sort of script that actually visits that page with the **.pdf** extension, and saves it.

I recommend [wkhtmltopdf](http://wkhtmltopdf.org/) as I use it quite often and it renders PDF's very well. This will allow you to save the PDF to the file system.

Comment: Okie i understand . but how do i store the html before rendering ?

Comment: Can i use ERB module to render the partial in background and save it as html .

Comment: you simply tell this script what page to visit (so you would supply it the html version of the page) and it saves a PDF of the html. so once you 'install' that script, you would provide something like "wkhtmltopdf http://google.com /Desktop/google.pdf" and it turns google.com into a PDF and saves it at /Desktop